# SQL GROUPING SETS in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The code below is intended to provide SQL's GROUPING SETS functionality in Python with the aid of [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

[Background on SQL GROUPING SETS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

There are at least two advantages to doing this in Python:

- it is less verbose than SQL, and
- it provides a non-redundant set of aggregations without the need to manually specify them.

There is at least one disadvantage to doing this in Python:

- memory usage is quite likely higher than would be in SQL.

I am posting this question in the hopes that the code can be cleaned up. Secondarily I am posting to determine if anyone would find this useful. The example below has been tested with Python 2.7.6 and Pandas 0.15.1.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import itertools as it
import pandas as pd

from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

def powerset(iterable): 
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s,r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def grouper(df,grpby=None,aggfunc=None):
    ''' produces aggregate DataFrame from DataFrames for non-redundant groupings
       `workingdf` is used to avoid modifying original DataFrame
    '''
    uniqcols = (i for i in grpby if len(df[i].unique()) == 1)
    pwrset = (i for i in powerset(grpby))
    s = set()
    for uniqcol in uniqcols:
        for i in pwrset:
            if uniqcol in i:
                s.add(i) # add a level of aggregation only when non-redundant

    workingdf = df.copy()
    #for idx,i in enumerate(powerset(grpby)):
    for idx,i in enumerate(s):
        print('  grouping by: {}'.format(i))
        if i != (): 
            tmp = aggfunc( workingdf.groupby(i) )
        else:
            # hack to get output to be a DataFrameGroupBy object:
            #   insert dummy column on which to group by
            # old, naive code:
            #   tmp = aggfunc( workingdf )
            dummycolname = hash(tuple(workingdf.columns.tolist()))
            workingdf[dummycolname] = ''
            tmp = aggfunc( workingdf.groupby(dummycolname) )

        # drop the index and add it back
        if i == (): tmp.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
        else: tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)

        for j in grpby: 
            if j not in tmp: # if column is not in DataFrame add it
                tmp[j] = '(All)'

        # new list with all columns including aggregate ones; do this only once
        if idx == 0:
            finalcols = grpby[:]
            addlcols = [k for k in tmp if k not in grpby] # aggregate columns 
            finalcols.extend(addlcols)

        # reorder columns 
        tmp = tmp[finalcols] 

        # creation of final DataFrame
        if idx == 0:
            final = tmp; del tmp
        else: 
            final = pd.concat( [final,tmp] ); del tmp

    del workingdf

    final = final.sort(columns=finalcols)
    final.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

    return final

def agg(grpbyobj):
    ''' the purpose of this function is to: 
          specify aggregate operation(s) you wish to perform, 
          name the resulting column(s) in the final DataFrame.
    '''
    tmp = pd.DataFrame()
    tmp['Total (n)'] = grpbyobj['Total'].sum()
    return tmp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Area':['a','a','b',],
                       'Year':[2014,2014,2014,],
                       'Month':[1,2,3,],
                       'Total':[4,5,6,],})
    final = grouper(df,grpby=['Area','Year'],aggfunc=agg)
    print(final)

    # test against expected result 
    expected = '''{"Area":{"0":"(All)","1":"a","2":"b"},
                   "Year":{"0":2014,"1":2014,"2":2014},
                   "Total (n)":{"0":15,"1":9,"2":6}}'''
    testfinal = pd.read_json(expected)
    testfinal = testfinal[final.columns.tolist()] # reorder columns 
    try:
        # check_names kwarg True: compare indexes and columns 
        assert_frame_equal(final,testfinal,check_names=True)
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About this part:

```
def grouper(df,grpby=None,aggfunc=None):
    uniqcols = (i for i in grpby if len(df[i].unique()) == 1)
    pwrset = (i for i in powerset(grpby))
    s = set()
    for uniqcol in uniqcols:
        for i in pwrset:
            if uniqcol in i:
                s.add(i) # add a level of aggregation only when non-redundant
```

- The two optional arguments are in fact required by the function.
- The convention is that `i` is a loop variable of type `int`.
- Bug: `pwrset` is a generator expression. As such it can only be iterated through once, just like the iterator returned from `powerset(grpby)`. Using square brackets `[]` instead of `()` would turn it into a list comprehension and fix the bug.
- Changing the other generator expression into a list comprehension would allow you to swap the order of the nested for loops. This would be more natural since the nested loop is filtering `pwrset`, and more efficient because you could break out of the inner loop after first `s.add(i)`. Then `s` does not even need to be a `set` (because the rest of the code merely iterates over `s`). If you make `uniqcols` a `set` instead, the inner loop could be avoided altogether.

Revised code:

```
def grouper(df, grpby, aggfunc):
    uniqcols = set(col for col in grpby if len(df[col].unique()) == 1)
    s = [cols for cols in powerset(grpby) if not uniqcols.isdisjoint(cols)]
```